# How can you mount a Windows 10 partition that is not bootable and is still "in use" due to the hibernation issue

Tags: data-recovery

I've seen most of the forum answers to this issue, but all the fixes assume you can boot in Windows 10. 
Due to a Lenovo issue, i cannot boot my windows 10 OS, and in ubuntu i cannot recover the files because of the hybernation/fast startup issue.

What can i do?

EDIT: 
I have to say that the lenovo issue is: `Error 1962`. 
Which appear to be a common lenovo problem that most of the time is solved this way: https://howtoremove.guide/error-1962-lenovo-no-operating-system-found-fix/ 
Unfortunately, the fix did not work, and after contacting Lenovo support and ensuring disk storage functions with the BIOS, the only fix they could asses was reinstalling w10 with the Lenovo Recovery Download which re-installs and validates the W10 copy, but in the process deletes all the data. Which is the one thing we are trying to save.

EDIT 2 - THE FIX: Thanks for the comments and support, sadly none of the responses really answered the issue. Fortunately, the way to fix this is just to disconect the SATA HDD for the logical release, pluggin it back in, and do the usual linux files recovery. Then installing any OS you want.

Comment: Try to mount it read-only or loop-mount it read-only.

Comment: Not positive that this would work (hence why it's a comment) but you could try either/or resating your CMOS battery to reset your BIOS, or unplugging your hard drive and boot cycling without it. Ideally one of these will allow you to mount it as RW afterwards.

Comment: Cannot mount a a Read-only because w10 still "holds it" @sudodus.

Comment: And yeah @Minty, last thing to try is removing the hard drive, but as it is a company owned PC, that is the las thing they want to try. ikr!

Comment: [SOLVED] Error 1962: No operating system found. Lenovo K430  only boot Ubuntu, rename files
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243715 Normally you can manually mount read only. You may be able to remove hiberfile. https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation If work PC, get a Windows repair/recovery flash drive made from another similar Windows pc.

Answer (score 2):

In order of preference...

1. repair the "Lenovo" problem that won't let you boot Windows, then boot Windows, then fully shutdown Windows
2. boot a Windows Repair disc and run `chkdsk` (*or repair*) on the hard drive
3. (*and I hate to recommend this...*) use `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxx`. See `man ntfsfix` for more information about this command.

Comment: Oldfred posted a comment above with a link to 25 posts in Ubuntuforums.org which might fix #1 in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

THE FIX: Thanks for the comments and support, sadly none of the responses really answered the issue. Fortunately, the way to fix this is just to disconect the SATA HDD for the logical release, pluggin it back in, and do the usual linux files recovery. Then installing any OS you want. 
Dealing with the error 1962 should be addressed by using the LENOVO DATA RECOVERY TOOL

Comment: What is the "usual linux files recovery"? fsck? ntfsfix?